# Matching CLOSEST file in given ASCII Text Files

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, ascii, information-retrieval

**PROBLEM:**

I have around 20 ASCII text files, each having a size less than **10^9 Bytes**.Another ASCII text file (say FOO) is given. Program is to strategically match the contents of FOO with the given 20 files and print the name of CLOSEST matching file. The contents of FOO might only match partially.

Since file size is too large ,i'm wondering:

1.How to use Information Retrieval(since I don't know much about IR)

2.which data structure should i use to store such information

3.What would be the best Algorithm to implement it.

I know i'm asking too much, But really i'm stuck at this problem and not able to find out how to approach.Any help would be Appreciated.Thanks!

Comment: how about scan all the files and create a n dimensional vector of words for each text file, then you can calculate the angle between the documets and select the closest one?

Comment: A simpler way would be to use the Jaccard Index http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index, although it might not deliver the same accuracy as cosine similarity. Note that this techniques operate on normalized word counts.

Comment: You really need to define "closest". If the test file matches all the words in file #1, but with the words in reverse order (i.e. "the quick red fox" and "fox red quick the"), is it "closer" than if it matches file #2 exactly in order for the first 30%, but then has very little similarity afterwards? Is case significant? White space? Without a definition of "closest," you're going to have a tough time deciding what to compare.

Comment: Maybe create a [bloom filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) based off some features from a file (words, paragraphs, letters?) then check against each other?

Comment: To answer this you first need to specify what you want a little better. You need to do two things: 1. define 'closest' - minimum number of changed characters? Difference between two characters? e.g. is a->b better than a change from a->m, word difference? Are two consecutive changed letter better than changed letters far apart? 2. Since this is an optimization question what use case are you optimimizing for? A single test file? or many? Do the comparison files change with each test? Or are they the same each time.

Comment: Some application of Rabin Karp? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

So I assume a file contain some text. So we can say each one of the file is a big string. Now make 20 vectors or arrays. Go through the file and put each word as an element in the vector. Now create a vectors with a size of 20 to store the matching of each of the file Now create a word vector for the given file as well. Now create a loop to run through these vectors if at any given index you found a match with any of these 20 vectors and your given vectors. Increase the value for corresponding file in match storing vectors. At the end, the highest value in the match storing vector will indicate the file with the best match.

Answer (score 0):

Solution by Vampire Coder assumes that the documents are bag of words, meaning ordering of words doesn't matter. But by "match partially," you meant some of the sentences matching, then that won't do any good.

You could divide each document into overlapping subsets, and take the hash of each subset. Then you transform your document into a set of hashes. Then you could compare the hashes. This is one way you could do what you want to do.

For each document, once you have narrowed down potential matches, you can increase the resolution at which you divide your documents. Say you initially divided them into two, now you can divide them into 10. This is to minimize the running time.

Also you should use locality sensitive hashing algorithm like: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilsimsa_Hash

Answer (score 0):

My guess at "closest", is the file with the smallest diff between the 2 files.

I would look for a diff algorithm, or longest common subsequence https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem